# Golang: Reflect returns different kind when same value depending on initialisation

Tags: go, reflection, maps

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type MyStruct struct{}

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]any)
    m["key"] = make([]*MyStruct, 0)
    myStructs := m["key"]
    myStructsVal := reflect.ValueOf(&myStructs)
    fmt.Println(myStructsVal.Type().Kind())
    fmt.Println(myStructsVal.Type().Elem().Kind())

    nm := make(map[string][]*MyStruct)
    nm["key"] = make([]*MyStruct, 0)
    nmStructs := nm["key"]
    nmStructsVal := reflect.ValueOf(&nmStructs)
    fmt.Println(nmStructsVal.Type().Kind())
    fmt.Println(nmStructsVal.Type().Elem().Kind())
}
```

The following the output:

```
ptr
interface
ptr
slice
```

This means that `reflect` considers the first `myStructsVal` to be a pointer to an interface and the second `nmStructsVal` to be a pointer to slice. Am I wrong when I consider the treatment of both variables to be same by the reflect library? Am I missing something?

Any help or pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the [Go playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/cM7Sl7f0gad).

Comment: The code shows the type of the variables. The type of variable `myStructs` is `any`.  The type of variable `nmStructs` is `[]*MyStruct`.   Use `reflect.ValueOf(myStructs).Type()` to get the type of the value.

Comment: That hardly helps. Functions that use reflect generally take an `any` as an argument. So are you saying that if the same thing I did was in a function, behaviour would be different?

Comment: @arl In example #1 you are passing `*any([]*MyStruct)` to `reflect.ValueOf` (hence the output `ptr; interface`). In example #2 you are passing `*[]*MyStruct` to `reflect.ValueOf` (hence the output `ptr; slice`). The output matches the input.

Comment: Aren't the values same in both the cases though?

Comment: `*any` is not identical to `any`, regardless of what's stored inside the interface @arl. Also `*any` is not identical to, nor interchangeable with, `*[]*MyStruct`.

Comment: In addition to what has been explained: Using a pointer to the empty struct `struct{}` is a tremendous bad idea: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees (last paragraph)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *resolve* what an interface's backing type is, you can use `reflect.TypeOf`. Refer to the [godoc of the package](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect):

> Package reflect implements run-time reflection, allowing a program to manipulate objects with arbitrary types. The typical use is to take a value with static type interface{} and extract its dynamic type information by calling TypeOf, which returns a Type.
>
> A call to ValueOf returns a Value representing the run-time data. Zero takes a Type and returns a Value representing a zero value for that type.

Because you're asking for the value, you're getting exactly that. Look at this example instead:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    var x any = 5
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(x).Name()) // int
}
```